# Unable to install ATI Catalyst drivers under CentOS 7

Tags: centos, software-installation, fglrx

I'm getting an error running ./amd-driver-installer-14.20-x86.x86_64.run

```
# ./amd-driver-installer-14.20-x86.x86_64.run
Created directory fglrx-install.xjgOcJ
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing AMD Catalyst(TM) Proprietary Driver-14.20............................
=====================================================================
AMD Catalyst(TM) Proprietary Driver Installer/Packager
=====================================================================
Detected configuration:
Architecture: x86_64 (64-bit)
X Server: X.Org 6.9 or later 64-bit
```

Click next on the setup window, then this message appears:

[image]

"Your graphics adapter is not supported by this driver.  Installation will not proceed"

I'm running the 256MB ATI Mobility Radeon HD 3650 in a Dell Studio laptop.

Graphics performance is noticeably worse after updating to CentOS 7 (from Linux Mint 15 where I had Catalyst installed).

My next step was to grab the "legacy" drivers from ATI:

```
# ./amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13.1-legacy-linux-x86.x86_64.run
```

Clicked next at the opening window, then this appears: 
[image]

Here's the referenced log file:

```
# cat /usr/share/ati/fglrx-install.log 
Check if system has the tools required for installation.
fglrx installation requires that the system have kernel headers.  /lib/modules/3.10.0-123.6.3.el7.x86_64/build/include/linux/version.h cannot be found on this system.
One or more tools required for installation cannot be found on the system. Install the required tools before installing the fglrx driver.
Optionally, run the installer with --force option to install without the tools.
Forcing install will disable AMD hardware acceleration and may make your system unstable. Not recommended.


# yum list kernel*
Installed Packages
kernel.x86_64                                                              3.10.0-123.el7                                                 @anaconda
kernel.x86_64                                                              3.10.0-123.6.3.el7                                             @updates 
kernel-devel.x86_64                                                        3.10.0-123.6.3.el7                                             @updates 
kernel-headers.x86_64                                                      3.10.0-123.6.3.el7                                             @updates 
kernel-tools.x86_64                                                        3.10.0-123.6.3.el7                                             @updates 
kernel-tools-libs.x86_64                                                   3.10.0-123.6.3.el7                                             @updates
```

So the kernel headers are in fact, installed.

What next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, both messages are very clear:

- > Your graphics adapter is not supported by this driver. Installation will not proceed

  This means that the version of the drivers don't support the "ATI Mobility Radeon HD 3650" adapter that you have. You may try the legacy, which you did and lead you to the second eror.
- > Check if system has the tools required for installation.
  >   fglrx installation requires that the system have kernel headers.  **/lib/modules/3.10.0-123.6.3.el7.x86_64/build/include/linux/version.h cannot be found on this system.**
  >   One or more tools required for installation cannot be found on the system. **Install the required tools before installing the fglrx driver.**

  This means that there are missing packages/libraries that the driver needs to work. Use `yum whatprovides /lib/modules/3.10.0-123.6.3.el7.x86_64/build/include/linux/version.h` and install the desired package. In some cases (like Debian) this file isn't there either, in which case creating a symlink to the file is necessary with `ln -s ../generated/uapi/linux/version.h /lib/modules/3.10.0-123.6.3.el7.x86_64/build/include/linux/version.h`, which I don't recommend you to do.

So, what's left? Well, instead of all of that, just try to use `--listpkg` to find if your version is supported and `--buildpkg` to build a package to install the driver.

Comment: I used `--buildpkg` to try installing the RPM. Dependanceis were added and it looked like a good install.  Ran `aticonfig --install`, then rebooted.  Gnome won't load - hangs on post.